# Proof of the need of an even degree for a graph to be factorizable

Tags: graph-theory

For a graph to be factorizable, it seems it has to be of even degree. Could anyone give a simple proof thereof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: even degree? What is the degree of a graph? Perhaps you meant odd order? As in an odd number of vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graph $G$ that is factorizable ($1$-factorizable) must have an even number of vertices. This is because for it to be factorizable, in particular it must contain at least one factor ($1$-factor, also known as matching). So it must contain a generating subgraph that is regular of degree $1$. If $G$ had an odd number of vertices this would be impossible because the generating $1$-regular subgraph would have an odd number of vertices of odd degree.

This is impossible, every graph has an even number of vertices of odd degree. As is explained [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181833/proving-that-the-number-of-vertices-of-odd-degree-in-any-graph-g-is-even).