# Show that K and K' cannot both contain an Eulerian trail

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eulerian-path

[image]

For question (b), I understand how to prove that they can't both contain an Eulerian trail--eulerian trail exists if and only if there are no more than 2 odd degrees of the vertices.
So for a complete graph, each vertex will have a degree of 5 as it is connected to 5 other vertices, so K'+k=5.

However, this is a bit I'm stuck on. I know the argument that odd + even =odd / even +odd = odd, and using numbers like 3,2 /2,3 definitely satisifes and answers the question. But doesn't the argument fail if we use 1,4/4,1?

Please advise.Thank you in advance. And sorry for any wrong title labelling or tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [eulerian trail/path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Properties) : An undirected graph has an Eulerian trail if and only if exactly two vertices have odd degree, and if all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a single connected component.

**Case_1 :** We have given $6$ vertices, let [degree sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence) of graph $K$ has **even degree** of each vertices (*i.e.,* number of odd degree vertex is $0$). So, $K$ would have eulerian trail by the definition.

But, complement of $K$(*i.e.* $K'$) would be odd degree of each vertex ($5 - even = odd$). So, $K'$ can not be  eulerian trail by the definition.

**Case_2 :** We have given $6$ vertices, let [degree sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence) of graph $K$ has **odd degree** of exactly two vertices (*i.e.,* number of odd degree vertex is $2$). So, $K$ would have eulerian trail by the definition.

But, complement of $K$(*i.e.* $K'$) would be odd degree of exactly three vertex ($5 - even = odd$). So, $K'$ can not be  eulerian trail by the definition. Since $K'$ has more than $2$ odd degree vertices.

---

**Comment :** Case (b) is possible only when number of vertices are odd. (*e.g.,* $C_n$).

Comment: thank you. Very comprehensive reply. However, my query was that as the requirement was that it cannot have MORE THAN 2 odd degree vertices. What if K' was 1, (odd but less than 2) and K was 4?

Comment: @CCC, you are welcome.It is not possible that number of odd degree vertices of simple graph is only one. Since, [**according to theorem : number of odd degree vertices should be even.**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181833/proving-that-the-number-of-vertices-of-odd-degree-in-any-graph-g-is-even).

Comment: And when number of odd degree vertices is $4$ of graph $K$. This case will be **case-2**. Means $K$ can not be eulerian trail by the definition, but $K'$ would be.