# Prove that in any convex polyhedron, the number of faces that have an odd number of edges is even.

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra

> Prove that in any convex polyhedron, the number of faces that have an odd number of edges is even.

I attempted to prove this by contradiction but didn't make any progress.

Comment: Each edge borders exactly two faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a graph in the following way:

- Vertices are faces of the polyhedron
- Two vertices are connected if their corresponding faces share an edge

Observe that the odd-edged faces are exactly the vertices of odd degree in our graph. We know that [the number of vertices of odd degree in any graph $G$ is even](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/181833/274352).

Answer (score 4):

Let the faces be $F_1,\ldots,F_k$. Consider the sum $S=n_1+\cdots+n_k$
where face $F_i$ has $n_i$ edges.
This sum counts each edge twice: $S$ is even. So the number of $j$ for
which $n_j$ is odd must be even.

Comment: well @Lord, this argument alone only holds for 1 type of faces, or for 1 odd-polygonal face type, while all others are even-polygonal. But why this rules out say 7 triangles plus 3 pentagons?

Answer (score 1):

I'll elaborate a bit more, which'll helpfully help anybody interested get off on the right foot.

---

Let $G$ be a graph depicting the planar representation of a convex polyhedron.  Let $F \in \Bbb Z^{+}$ denote the total number of faces in $G$ and $f_{1},f_{2},...,f_{F}\in \Bbb Z^{+}$ denote the respective number of edges of each of the $F$ faces of $G$.  Recall $$\sum_{i=1}^F f_{i} =2e,$$ where $e\in \Bbb Z^{+}$ denotes the total of number of edges of $G$.  Hence $$f_{1}+f_{2}+...+f_{F}=2e.$$

---

There we have it.  You just use some basic properties of number theory/ arithmetic/ algebra to deduce that there must be an even number of odd $f$'s so that ultimately their sum is an even number.  For example, note that $2+3+5=10$ is an even number, but $2+3+5+7=17$ is not.