# How to prove that in an arbitrary graph the number of vertices with odd degree is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, order-theory

I know that degree of a vertex of an (undirected) graph is the number of edges incident to the vertex. I need to prove that in an arbitrary graph the number of vertices with odd degree is even. How to formally prove it?

Comment: Hint : Hand-shake lemma

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181833/proving-that-the-number-of-vertices-of-odd-degree-in-any-graph-g-is-even).

Answer (score 0):

The sum of degrees of all vertices is even. Thus the number of odd-degree vertices must be even, since otherwise the first sum is odd (even-degree vertices do not affect the parity of the first sum).

Answer (score 0):

I proved this many hard ways. Years later I found this. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoRhmz_OSBY) is the best way!