# Which of these values are possible for $M$ and $N$

Tags: graph-theory

Can anyone explain this question. In an undirected graph $G$, the number of vertices having odd and even degrees are $M$ and $N$ respectively. Which of these values are possible for $M$ and $N$?

1. $M = 96, N = 11$
2. $M = 101, N = 10$
3. $M = 97, N = 31$
4. $M = 103, N = 12$

Comment: Hint: each edge joins two vertices

Comment: The sum of the degrees of all vertices is even (twice the number of edges), the number of vertices with odd degree ($M$) must be even.

Answer (score 1):

$M$, the number of odd degree vertices has to be even, see

[Proving that the number of vertices of odd degree in any graph G is even](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181833/proving-that-the-number-of-vertices-of-odd-degree-in-any-graph-g-is-even).

This leaves only answer A, which must then be correct be the exclusion principle.